# export mysql tables in CVS into a ZIP file

Tags: php, mysql, zip, export-to-csv

I have done a script in PHP to export a MySQL table into a CVS file when clicking a button. It's working fine but now I need to export 1 table per CSV file, all this in a ZIP (or RAR) file when clicking a button.

Basically it should be:
Export table:

> mytable.csv

Export all tables:

> export.ZIP containing:
>
> --mytable1.csv
>
> --mytable2.csv
>
> --mytable3.csv

I could loop the export function for each table but that will not put everyting into the ZIP:

```
/* EXPORT ALL TABLES */
if (isset($_POST['export_all_tables'])){
    $Qlist_table = $pdo->prepare('SHOW TABLES');
    $Qlist_table->execute(array(''));
    foreach ($Qlist_table as $Alist_table)
      export_table($Alist_table[0]);
}


 function export_table($table_to_export){
$Qselect = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table_to_export.''); 
    $Qselect->execute(array(''));
    $results = $Qselect->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
...
...
...

    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/vnd.ms-excel\n");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo $outputCsv;
    exit();
}
```

I don't think you need all the code of the export function, if yes let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you putting the files into a `.zip`?

Comment: use ZipArchive() class and add 1 file at a time using addFile() method.

Comment: I would like to download the file directly. I'm now using affFile(). I will update my question as soon as I'm done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution thanks to addFile(). Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['export_all_tables'])){
    // Name of the file to export
    $date = date('Y_m_j_H\hi');
    $fileName = 'Export_all_'.$date.'.zip';

    // Headers to create the ZIP file
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/zip;\n");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public");
    header("Expires: 0");

    // We create the ZIP file       
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $result_zip = $zip->open($fileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);    // We open the file
    if ($result_zip === TRUE) {

        $Qlist_table = $pdo->prepare('SHOW TABLES');
        $Qlist_table->execute(array(''));

        // For each table
        foreach ($Qlist_table as $Alist_table) {

                $content = export_table($Alist_table[0]);
                $fileName = $Alist_table[0].'_'.$date.'.csv';   
                $zip->addFile($fileName, $fileName);            // We add the CSV file from the server
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Failed, code:' . $result_zip;
    }   
    readfile("Export_all.zip");             // To download the ZIP file
    exit(); 
}
```

and the exporttable function ends like that to write the file on the server:

```
$fh = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("Can't open file");
$stringData = $outputCsv;   // outputCsv is the content of the table
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```